# Mongo find() produces {} along with expected results

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello I am trying to filter out for only video_trim in my query but the code still produces empty objects in the place of filtered out content

here is the code

```
const findTrims = (db, cb) => {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection(documentName);

    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}, {projection:{ _id: 0, name: 0, label: 0 }}).toArray((err, docs) => {
      // An error occurred we need to return that to the given 
      // callback function
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");
      console.log(docs)

      return cb(null, docs);
    });
  }
module.exports = {
findTrims: cb => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err)
      }
      console.log('Connected successfully to server')

      const db = client.db(dbName)

      findTrims(db, (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err)
        }

        // return your documents back to the given callback
        return cb(null, docs)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

the output of the find is this

[ {}, {}, {}, {}, { Video_trim: ' ' } ]

How do I get rid of the {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass some conditions to filter. f.e. `collection.find({"Video_trim": { $exists: true }}, { _id: 0, name: 0, label: 0 })`

Comment: This partially solved the problem but the id is showing up now for some odd reason

Comment: what exact you want, only "Video_trim"?

Comment: Yea [ { Video_trim: ' cut2' } instead of [ { _id: 5a6785ef6503fdac08d60ac5, Video_trim: ' cut2' },

Comment: What version of Mongo do you have?

Comment: version v3.4.10